# query for grouping multiple same record into 1 line

Tags: sql, postgresql

Have a problem find a query for my tables

I have 2 tables table A and table B as follow

```
table A 
---------------------
|   Name   | addrid |
---------------------
|   zlai   |   1    |
|   blai   |   2    |

table B 
---------------------
| addrid |   addr     |
---------------------
|   1    |   AMERICA  |
|   1    |   SPAIN    |
|   1    |   MEXICO   |
|   2    |   TURKEY   |
```

The result I need is

```
--------------------------
|   Num  | Name  | addr    |
--------------------------
|    1   | zlai  | AMERICA |               
|        |       | SPAIN   |
|        |       | MEXICO  |
|    2   | blai  | TURKEY  |
```

Query I have tried so far

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3ac39/12

Comment: do you mind to modify your data table in your question, especially about `Num`, so it is clearly explained what you need is an ordered ascending number NOT an `addrid`, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to modified the `addrid` values by 101 and 325 (for example)

```
table A 
---------------------
|   Name   | addrid |
---------------------
|   zlai   |   101  |
|   blai   |   325  |

table B 
---------------------
| addrid |   addr     |
---------------------
|   101  |   AMERICA  |
|   101  |   SPAIN    |
|   101  |   MEXICO   |
|   325  |   TURKEY   |
```

the query is:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN No != 1
             THEN ''
             ELSE CAST(row AS VARCHAR(20))
        END  AS Num,
        CASE WHEN No != 1
             THEN ''
             ELSE name
        END  AS name,
        addr
FROM
        (
          SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.addrid 
                                     ORDER BY name DESC) AS No,
                  name, 
                  addr,
                  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a.addrid) "row"
          FROM    a LEFT JOIN b ON a.addrid = b.addrid
        ) a
ORDER   BY row
```

and the result is same as you want.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a1b74/1/0)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN No != 1
             THEN ''
             ELSE CAST(a.addrid AS VARCHAR(20))
        END  AS Num,
        CASE WHEN No != 1
             THEN ''
             ELSE name
        END  AS name,
        addr
FROM
        (
          SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.addrid 
                                     ORDER BY name DESC) AS No,
                  name, 
                  addr,
                  a.addrid
          FROM    a LEFT JOIN b ON a.addrid = b.addrid
        ) a
ORDER   BY a.addrid
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/704f5/2)

Comment: thanks.. beside answering my question it also helps me understand "PARTITION"

Comment: @muhnizar `PARTITION` splits the records into group. So in this case he `ROW_NUMBER()` runs for every group of `addrid`.

Comment: @491243 what if the `addrid` is not (1,2) but for example (101,325)?

Comment: @muhnizar what do you mean by `Num` column? is it an ascending ordered number OR it retrieved from `addrid` column?

Comment: @nametal It's supposed to be ascending ordered number! so what do you suggest?

Comment: muhnizar, that's the point. 
@491243 I think your answer is not completely correct. I post an answer below based on yours

Comment: @nametal no, you don;t understand. `No` is a calculated column not a `addrid `

Comment: @nametal well i'm not a mind reader. and to the OP it didn't say that it doesn't need to use the `addrid` but the calculated column. *sigh*

Comment: @491243 at a glance, I thought that `Num` with ordered number is more intuitive & reasonable in that case. So I took an initiative to ask it to the OP

Answer (score 1):

**[Here is the SQLFIddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3ac39/76)**

**Below is the Sample Query Which you can try :**

```
select Case rownum when 1 then cast(addrid as varchar(20)) else '' end as addrid,
       Case rownum when 1 then cast(name as varchar(20)) else '' end as name,
       addr
from (select a.addrid,a.name,b.addr,dense_rank() over (partition by a.addrid order by b.addr) as rownum
  from a,b
 where a.addrid = b.addrid) T
```